# App terminating due to 'Watchdog' error with Hot Restart

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Not long ago, I mistakenly deleted most of the 'Local' folder on my user profile, causing numerous issues with programs that were installed there or had some assets there. In the same way, my Hot Restart provisioning was mucked up, with an error saying the keychain didn't match with whatever was set somewhere else. So, I reset all the provisioning, and I am able to build now, but upon attempting to test on my iPad, it will try to load for a while, and then crash in a very timed fashion.

The debug output simply says that the 'app has terminated' or something along the lines of Hot Restart closing due to my explicit ending of the app (I didn't touch it at any point).

I looked into the device log, and this pops up at the end:

```
Provision violated for watchdog scene-create: <FBSProcessResourceProvision: 0x280cfb600; allowance: <; FBSProcessResourceAllowance; type: realTime; timeValue: 16.60s>; violated: YES>
```

```
Executing termination for reason (none) with request: <FBSProcessTerminationRequest: 0x283853500; label: "watchdog provision violated"; exceptionCode: "Watchdog Violation (0x8BADF00D)"; reportType: CrashLog; explanation: "scene-create watchdog transgression: com.companyname.TraceIt exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 16.60 seconds">
```

I did my own counting, and it does seem the app attempts loading for 20+ seconds, which, of course, 'Watchdog' then terminates due to the time constraint violation.
But this didn't happen before I deleted most of the Local folder, it was typically less than 10 seconds.

Could this at all be related to provisioning issues? I know that when it was displays the certificate in debug output, the team profile code is wrong, but it seems to attempt to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a static DataRepository object created in the App class, but in its constructor was `Task.Run([method]).Wait();`, so the App class never reached the class' actual constructor. Obviously, it was an infinite wait, hence nothing progressed until that finished. I removed the .Wait, now it works.